# How to populate automatically date column when any DML operation performed

Tags: mysql, datatable

I have a table with the following fields: username, email, password. Also, I add `created_date` and `updated_date`.

I want to get operation date stored automatically in the table when someone performs insert/update operation.

Anybody has the solution?

Comment: Have you considered using triggers?

Comment: yeah, I didn't think about that. thank you so much